# Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a simple code on appscript to get Google Drive file names out of the URL

```
function FileName (URL) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  return ss.getName();
}
```

When I run that I get an error:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call
> SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions:
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (linha 6).

I've already enabled Drive and Sheets API in the Advanced Google Services area, so the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" should be ok, but it is not.

How could I make that work?

I've created a sample sheet in [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QzzgpFlqqiVldu8cIrW0v_dLanrkyft7IK5c37UPpjw/edit#gid=0) with the problem replication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanation of the issue:

You are using a custom function.

It is very well explained in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> If your custom function throws the error message You do not have
> permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization
> and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

As the message clearly states, you are not allowed to use services that require authorization such as `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL)` within a custom function.

There is also a table that particularly points out that `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);` can not be used within a custom function:

[image]

### **Workarounds:**

You can use regular functions in multiple ways:

1. Implemented as custom menu buttons,
2. Execute them from the script editor,
3. Execute them via [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers),
4. Create an addon menu etc.

**Regular function version of your script**:

```
function FileName () {
  var URL = "spreadsheet_url"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(ss.getName());
}
```

Upon **execution** (see screenshot), this script will set the value of cell `A1` of `Sheet1` to the name of the spreadsheet file.

[image]

I would advice you to look for the functions I used in this script in the official documentation to see what each of them does.

**Update:**

I just opened your sheet and saw that you are using `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);` but this method works only for spreadsheets hence the class name `SpreadsheetApp`. If you want to open a file ID then you need to use [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid). I see in the first column you have file Urls but there is not method to open a file by its URL. The id from a file like that:

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-2L5kGZWbUa_p7iLgBBa59QqZiyIhgp/view?usp=sharing`

is:

`1d-2L5kGZWbUa_p7iLgBBa59QqZiyIhgp`

Therefore you need to use

`var files = DriveApp.getFileById('1d-2L5kGZWbUa_p7iLgBBa59QqZiyIhgp')`

A code snippet will be like that:

```
function FileName () {
  var URL = "1d-2L5kGZWbUa_p7iLgBBa59QqZiyIhgp"
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(URL);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(file.getName());
}
```

Please familiarize yourself with GAS because this question just became a question that needs more focus.

Comment: actually that's a prob in the sample I created. My goal is to get spreadsheets names. I liked your second solution though, seems more generic.

Comment: @abutremutante but in the first column you have file urls. Not spreadsheets. Anyway, see my next code snippet. I already provided information to 3 different problems. It is now up to you to understand what are the next steps. 1) I gave you expalanation and workarounds how to use a regular function because custom functions don't work like that and you have posted a similar question regarding that in the past. 2) I wrote for you a script to read spreadsheet urls and paste the names to the sheet 3) I did the same as 2) for files. This question is about to cross the lines of getting closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Could I ask an extra favor? Could you provide an example of using simple triggers? Checked the documentation you linked but couldn't understand how to apply that into my case

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is just granting myself permission using a directive from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes

Particularly:
[Auth Scopes Google Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY1f5.png)

From this example, I just added the "oauthscopes" at the highest level in the appscript.json as it states. I deleted the email scope, kept the spreadsheet scope and deleted the ".readonly". When I hit save, and re-ran (from a function assigned to an "image over cells" button), Google prompted me to authorize permissions to my Apps Script file.