# Why can't I open a file by ID that I have installed my add-on in?

Tags: google-apps-script, post, google-sheets, web-applications, scopes

According to the Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#openbyidid):

> #### openById(id)
>
> Opens the spreadsheet with the given ID. ...
>
> ...
>
> ##### Authorization
>
> Scripts that use this method require authorization with one or more of the following scopes:
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

I would like to use `openById` with the `spreadsheets.currentonly` scope since it suits my needs. However, even after adding the scope to the `appsscript.json` manifest, the following code fails for me:

```js
const sheet_id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id);
```

> Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

I understand that I could just use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` scope, but since the docs say I should be able to use `spreadsheets.currentonly`, that is what I want to do. What am I doing wrong here?

---

Update:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64896152/11853309) is related, but the workarounds suggested don't work for me. The code snippet I shared above was executed in the script editor. I also don't intend to create a custom function. I intend to run this code in the `doPost(e)` function of a web app script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth scope ids are sometimes reachable links that can provide useful information about the scope.

I got the following message after navigating to [`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly`](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly):

> *You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid or it refers to a newer scope that is outside the domain of this legacy API.*
>
> *This API was built at a time when the scope name format was not yet standardized. This is no longer the case and all valid scope names (both old and new) are catalogued at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes. Use that webpage to lookup (manually) the scope name associated with the API you are trying to call and use it to craft your OAuth2 request.*

Ultimately, I ended up [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets) which lists the following scopes for the Sheets API:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`

It looks like the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly` scope is no longer valid. I suspect this happened as a result of Version 3 of the Sheets API hitting its sunset date on August 2, 2021 (a few weeks ago as of this writing). Maybe the scope wasn't carried over to Version 4 of the Sheets API.

This issue certainly deserves further investigation. I suggest that you report the issue using Google's Issue Tracker using the following link:

https://issuetracker.google.com/components/191608.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the corresponding issue on Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197880233