# Have I created a Custom Function or a Script Function in Google Apps Script? ("You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById”)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I’ve searched similar questions on multiple threads, but something still isn’t making sense.

Here is some minimal reproducible code to copy a range from the active spreadsheet to a destination spreadsheet (anyone with the link can edit).

```
function CopyRange02(){
var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sss.getActiveSheet(); 
var range = ss.getRange('A1:D5'); 
var data = range.getValues();
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hWhVtBTTzhkTM1gu8Xu42R34f_aVv7wTF9sNynErCUc');
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('PasteIntoHere'); 
ts.getRange('A1:D5').setValues(data); 

}
```

In one of my projects, this code runs fine. When copied into a different project and run from there, it generates the error:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById

From other research, I understand the the method `SpreadsheetApp.openById` works in “Script Functions” but not in “Custom Functions”.

Why would the exact same code be handled in one project as a "Script Function" and run without errors, while the same code seems to be handled as a "Custom Function" in a different project, where the code fails?

Comment: A custom function is a function you place in a cell like the built in `=SUM()`.  So you would type in a cell `=MYFUNC()` and this function would perform calcs and return a value to the cell that contains the function.  If you are trying to `openById()` from a custom function it requires authorization to access the file which it can not do.  However, if you you use a App Script function you will be asked to allow access to the services specified in you App Script project and you can.  But you would need to run from a menu or button.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Rubén. I re-worded my original question to include a minimum reproducible example. Please note that, while I understand what a Custom Function is, I don't know why the same piece of code is sometimes treated as a Custom Function and sometimes as an App Script function.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets with a bounded Google Apps Script project or with an Editor Add-on, a [*custom function*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) is created by declaring a "Google Apps Script function", in other words, a *custom function* is a JavaScript function declared in a Google Apps Script project that is called from a Google Sheets formula.

Custom functions throw

> Exception: You do not have permission to call *something*

when a method that require authorization like `SpreadsheetApp.openById`
is used because custom functions can't call methods that requires authorization to run.

Other functions might throw the same error when they call methods that have not authorized to run under certain context. When running a function from the Google Apps Script script editor usually the authorization flow will be trigged authomatically, but on other contexts or on special circunstances the error will just be logged, i.e. when an installable trigger call a function that requires authorization but the authorization wasn't given for the required authorization scopes.

On Google Apps Script projects using the Google Cloud default project the authorization is managed by adding authorization scopes to the Google Apps Script manifest. By default the most common authorization scopes are added authomatically unless the manifest is edited manually.

On Google Apps Script projects using a Google Cloud standard project the OAuth consent screen should be set properly. If the project is used as an add-on the authorization scopes should also set properler in the Google Marketplace SDK.

To learn more about authorization scopes in Google Apps Script please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes

**Related**

- [Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64895519/1595451)

Comment: > ...in other words, a custom function is a JavaScript function declared in a Google Apps Script project that is called from a Google Sheets formula.    -- Very helpful!